# Multinomial combinations with inequalities

Tags: permutations, combinations

The number of ways you can arrange $N$ balls into $m$ bins such that each bin has $\{n_1, n_2,...,n_m\}$ balls ($n_1+n_2+...+n_m=N$) is the standard multinomial

$$\frac{N!}{n_1!n_2! \dots n_m!}$$

The question I have is how do you handle inequality constraints which may impact the number of combinations?

These could be that each bin has a lower and upper bound which is allowed

$$a_i \le n_i \le b_i$$

or that a linear combination inequality has to be true (or multiple linear inequalities)

$$s_i \le \sum_{i=1}^m c_i n_i \le t_i$$

(The inequalities could be one sided or two; could in theory require that bins {1,3,5} (say) have to have at least half the balls, or bins {2,4} (say) not more than 10)

Is there a formula to determine the number of combinations that can take into account those inequality constraints?

**EDIT**

Think found the formula for boxed constraints ($a_i \le n_i \le b_i$) , but don't see how it was derived (was given without proof), or how it can be extended to general linear inequalities

*J. N. Kapur “Measures of Information and Their Applications” (pg 238)*

Suppose $N$ balls are to be distributed among $n$ boxes in such a way that the $i$th box does not contain less than $Na_i$ balls and not more then $Nb_i$ balls ($0 \le a_i < b_i \le 1$), then the number of ways in which the $i$th box receives the $Np_i$ balls is given by

$$W = \frac{\left[ N (b_1 + \dots + b_n) \right] !}{ \left[ N (a_1 + \dots + a_n) \right] ! \prod_{i=1}^n (Np_i - Na_i)! (Nb_i - Np_i)!}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle might be relevant...